# Как получить данные из 3-х таблиц?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

База данных **MariaDB 10.2**. Есть три таблицы (3-я связующая):

```
------------------
| id | tool_name |
------------------
| 1  | bolt      |
------------------
| 2  | gayka     |
------------------
| 3  | samarez   |
------------------
| 4  | graver    |
------------------
...

------------------
| id | prop_name |
------------------
| 1  | stal      |
------------------
| 2  | stal1     |
------------------
| 3  | bronza    |
------------------
| 4  | bronza1   |
------------------
...

--------------------------------------------
| id | tool_name_id | prop_name_id | value |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       1      |      1       |   110 |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       1      |      2       |   12  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       1      |      3       |   13  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       2      |      4       |   1   |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       3      |      3       |   11  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |       2      |      3       |   12  |
--------------------------------------------
```

Не могу написать такой запрос, чтобы вытащил все инструменты со всеми характеристиками (таблица 2), чтобы потом записать в массив вида:

```
id (параметра) => {
  id ( инструмента) : value,
  ...
  id (инструмента) : value
}
...
id (параметра) => {
  id (инструмента) : value,
  ...
  id (инструмента) : value
}
```

Т.е. выбраны **ВСЕ** параметры и к ним инструменты со значением.

Всё, что я смог налаять:

```
select TP.id, TP.name, TP.description,
       GROUP_CONCAT(concat("{\"value\": ", FTP.value, ", \"line\": " , F.id, "}") separator ";") as json_lines_value 
from `tech_props` as `TP` 
inner join `flow_tech_props` as `FTP` on `FTP`.`tech_prop_id` = `TP`.`id` 
inner join `flows` as `F` on `F`.`id` = `FTP`.`flow_id` 
group by `TP`.`id` 
order by `TP`.`id` asc
```

Результат:

```
1   min_height  Минимальная высота стеклопакета {"value": 12, "line": 43};{"value": 12, "line": 46}
3   max_height  Максимальная высота стеклопакета    {"value": 321, "line": 44}
7   argon       Возможность заполнения аргоном  {"value": 11, "line": 44};{"value": 0, "line": 70};{"value": 12, "line": 43}
```

Comment: Вы довольно запутанно изложили задачу. Есть "инструменты" (id, name), есть "свойства" (id, name) и есть "инструменты_свойства" (id, tool_name, prop_name, value). Вам нужно получить именно **свойства** и входящие в них инструменты в виде вложенного массива? Если так, то к чему тут null подставлять?

Comment: @nikitar Свойство->инструмент - значение. Да, действительно, `null` не к чему подставлять. Подправлю вопрос.

Comment: Вам критически важно формировать json на стороне базы? На порядок проще и удобнее это было бы сделать в приложении.

Comment: Попытался сделать то, что понял из описания - запрос получился прибзительно аналогичный, но добавил ключ - id свойства:
`SELECT
  p.id,
  p.prop_name,
  p.prop_desc,
  CONCAT('{"', p.id, '": ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"value": ', tp.value, ', "line": ', t.id, '}')), '}') json_props
FROM tools t
LEFT JOIN tools_properties tp ON t.id = tp.tool_name_id
INNER JOIN properties p ON tp.prop_name_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id`

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, `налаять`. Повеселился... :)

Comment: Замените абстрактные таблицы на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Ещё лучше - создайте fiddle. Покажите требуемый результат на именно показанных в INSERT INTO данных - сейчас результат никак с образцом данных не соотносится.